# jQuery opacity not working

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I am trying to change the opacity of the image after I click the red button
instead of adding the different image, and I should not see the red button on the new image

My JS code is below.

http://jsfiddle.net/mwPeb/7/

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".specialHoverOne").hover(function () {
            //  alert("i am here");
            $(".ctaSpecialOne").css("visibility", "visible");

        },

        function () {
            $(".ctaSpecialOne").css("visibility", "hidden");
        });

        $(".ctaSpecialOne").click(function (e) {
            alert("clicked");
            e.preventDefault();
            //$(this).closest('.specialHoverOne').unbind("mouseenter").end().parent().siblings('a').children("img").attr("src", //"http://imgs.zinio.com/magimages/62898189/2012/416242497_200.jpg");                
            $(this).css({
                'opacity': 50
            });

        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd spend some quality time cleaning up the coding here, it's a bit difficult to find anything and the structure is a bit hard to follow.

If I'm understanding correctly, I believe this is the line you need to make the image above the red button change opacity when said red button is clicked.

```
$(this).parent().prev().prev().css({'opacity':.5});
```

More specifically;

```
$(".ctaSpecialOne").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();            
  $(this).parent().prev().prev().css({'opacity':.5});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mwPeb/11/

Comment: +1 for DOM traversal.  All the more reason to clean up the code and pass in the ID that needs opacity.

Comment: @douglas: thanks for the reply I am trying to recive this kind of opacity https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B5pgxrT9wSU7bUx0Ql9sOVFzb0E

Comment: @douglas: can we make the red button to completely hide once the image is added...since after i mouse hover i see the red button again

Comment: You could add `$(this).remove();` after the opacity change to remove the red link entirely. I think that's what you want?

Comment: @DouglasA.Crosby: thanks itw working but i have another doubt I am trying to recive this kind of opacity docs.google.com/open?id=0B5pgxrT9wSU7bUx0Ql9sOVFzb0E  with a box image on current image how to schieve it

Comment: @duglas the opacity should be like this https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3IBJKENGE7RS1lwZzhYbTNRbkk/edit

Comment: Hm.. It looks like the images have about the same opacity. Could you explain what you're looking for more in depth? http://jsfiddle.net/mwPeb/14/ has the same opacity as the link you sent me and shows how to move an image above the opaque image. Perhaps revise your original question above so you can more fully explain what you're looking for; or post a new one if it's a different topic.

Answer (score 0):

You want the opacity of the red button to change on click?  Or the image above it?  For starters, to set the opacity, you would change your line:

```
$(this).css({'opacity':50});
```

to:

```
$(this).css({ opacity: 0.5 });
```

In your current fiddle, you'll see that sets the opacity of the red button.  If you want it to set something else, you now have the syntax.

**Update:**
Instead of wiring up a bunch of .click() events that repeat the same code, might be best to create a function

```
function setThisOpacity(id) {
    $("#" + id).css({ opacity: 0.5 });
    //do other stuff if you need to
}
```

And then in your html markup, just add an `onclick="setThisOpacity(someID);"` where `someID` is an actual ID to the item you want to set the opacity.

Comment: @ethom10: thanks for your reply I wanted to change the opacity of the image

Comment: @ethom: thanks for your reply but i am not able to see the change http://jsfiddle.net/mwPeb/10/ i added the id and js <img id="ko" style="border: 1px solid red;" src="http://imgs.zinio.com/magimages/62898189/2012/416242497_200.jpg" class="cover">